# How to calculate the output impedance of this circuit?

Tags: impedance, current-source, basic, input-impedance

This is a hybrid-pi model of a BJT, and I want to know its output impedance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOomkL.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I know that I should short the input ports, place a voltage on the output ports, calculate the consequent current and finally apply Ohm's law, but I have no idea how to deal with that CCCS.

According to the key, the input impedance is Rc. Does this implies that the CCCS can be seen as a ideal current source, and thus considered as open circuit?

Comment: You mention "input impedance" yet I see no input. Be clear about the nets between which you want to determine the impedance. For example mark those nets inp and inn in the schematic and say that you want to determine the impedance between those points.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Edited now

Comment: Impedance is the ratio of dV/dI where dV is a small voltage change and dI is the resulting current change. Consider the change in the current coming out of a **constant** current source when the voltage is changed. But cccs1 is not a constant current source. Or is it ? What determines it's current ? The current through... which is the same current as .... hint: assume that current has a certain value, will it change if the voltage between inp and inn changes ?

Comment: @FakeMoustache But shouldn't constant current sources be seen as open circuit when calculating input impedance?

Comment: Yes but cccs1 is a **controlled** current source. So **only** if it's current is actually constant and **not** depending on the voltage between inp and inn can you assume it to be an open when determining the impedance between inp and inn.

Comment: @FakeMoustache The current through CCCS1 is determined by that of R1, which is further determined by the voltage on R1. I wonder when we have a small voltage change between inp and inn, that change will be applied on which component, R1 or CCCS1?

Comment: @FakeMoustache Oh I understand now! I've to admit that this post is an "XY problem". In the actual problem, the current of R1 and CCCS1 "cancels out" each other. Thanks for your help and hints!

Comment: To answer that, think about what happens when for example the voltage at inp increases a little bit. Does this voltage change appear across R1 ? Only if the current through would also change. But the current through R1 is set by... CCCS1. So that voltage change will appear across CCCS1 and it will not change the current through R1 and CCCS1.

Comment: Actually they do not cancel out but they "bite eachother's tail" it is like R1 says to CCCS1: I see x Amps flowing, then CCCS1 says: OK, then I will generate a current of x Amps, this current flows through R1 etc...

Comment: @FakeMoustache Let's judge R1 and CCCS1 as a whole entity. Then they'll be a zero-ohm resistor, right?

Comment: Why ? I would say infinite impedance Z = dV/dI  If you change V, I does not change so no matter what dV is, dI is zero Z = dV / 0 = infinite.

Comment: @FakeMoustache Oh yes, indeed, that should be infinite. The result of R2 can be explained now.

Comment: What does 'R1.i / 1' mean?

Comment: @Chu It means the current through CCCS1 equals to "1" * "R1.i", where R1.i stands for the current flow through resister R1. If it was "R1.i 42", then the current through CCCS1 would be 42 times R1.i.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This circuit model is a logical impossibility.

The control current of the CCCS is the same as its output current. If the gain of the CCCS were anything other than 1, it would be obvious why this is a problem: a current can't be \$Z\$ times itself for any value of \$Z\$ other than 1. (except of course if the current happens to be 0).

Setting the gain to 1 makes this logical contradiction seem to disappear, but the circuit model is still a poor one --- in any real circuit there'd be uncertainty about what that gain is exactly.

So, there's no more sense to trying to reason about this circuit than there is to contemplating the equation

$$3 = 2\times{}5$$

**Edit**

The question has been clarified to indicate this is meant to be a simplification of the hybrid pi model of a BJT. Here's the usual hybrid pi model:
[image]
(source: [Wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:H_pi_model.svg))

The issue with your model is resolved by including the \$r_o\$ element.

Comment: In fact, this is a "simplified simplified" hybrid-pi model of a BJT and I was trying to calculate Ro. As I've said, this post is an XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378. Sorry for the confusion caused.

Comment: @sunqingyao, then it's over-simplified. For one thing, a BJT has three terminals, not two.

Comment: Exactly. Question has been edited to address my original intention, if this matter. Anyway, I've understood the reason now.

Comment: @sunqingyao, To make the model make sense you need to include the \$r_o\$ resistance between collector and emitter. This will resolve the logical impossibility of your model.